# SQL: Need to get MAX values from one table and divide by the total number of rows in another table

Tags: sql

I have a table with a bunch of scores for lessons, on a user by user basis

```
------------------------
|uid |lesson_id |score |
------------------------
|1   |0         |20    |
|1   |0         |25    |
|1   |0         |15    |
|1   |0         |40    |
|1   |1         |70    |
|1   |0         |10    |
|1   |1         |20    |
|1   |1         |55    |
|1   |1         |55    |
|1   |0         |5     |
|1   |2         |65    |
------------------------
```

I also have a table of all possible lessons that can be scored:

```
------------
|lesson_id |
------------
|0         |
|1         |
|2         |
|3         |
|4         |
|5         |
------------
```

I need to calculate the maximum score for each lesson in the second table from the scores in the first table, and take an average of that over the number of lessons in the second table:

So, the maximum scores for the scores table are (for user 1):

```
-----------------------
|lesson_id |max_score |
-----------------------
|0         |40        |
|1         |70        |
|2         |65        |
-----------------------
```

I need to sum them: 175 and divide by the total number of lessons in table 2: 6 which should give the answer 29.16

Any ideas how to do this in a single statement?

I can get the average of all max values for the scores table (for user 1) like so:

```
SELECT AVG(max_score) AS avg_max_score FROM 
(
    SELECT uid, lesson_id, MAX(score) AS max_score FROM cdu_user_progress 
    AND uid =1
    GROUP BY lesson_id 
) AS m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    AVG(max_score)
FROM
   (

    SELECT
         lesson.lesson_id,
         max(isNull(score,0)) as max_score
    FROM
         lesson
    LEFT JOIN
         cdu_user_progress
    ON
         lesson.lesson_id = cdu_user_progress.lesson_id
    GROUP BY
         lesson.lesson_id
   ) AS m
```

Comment: How do I adjust this so it extracts on a user by user basis (the uid in table 1)?

Comment: @user3241112, just add to the outer select the user ID and add a group by for that... Also, add the user id to the inner pre-query and group by user added to the existing lesson ID too.

Comment: Do you have a table that holds the users? You'd need to reference that or else you'd end up collapsing the left join.